# how to integrate GSA with Day CQ

Tags: content-management-system, google-search-appliance

How should I connect DAY from GSA? I would like to know if there is any way to integrate GSA with Day CQ5 (CMS). Your valuables thoughts are invited.

Would appreciate a quick turnaround.

Comment: What do you mean by GSA?  Google Search Appliance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most flexible way is to make a http request and parse the xml response into a result view

Answer (score 1):

As you know, the GSA is a crawling search engine appliance. The lowest-tech way to go is to publish a dynamic sitemap that displays a link to every page on your site (that you want to index). Make the sitemap available on your CQ5 publisher/dispatcher. Then, enter the publisher/dispatcher's sitemap URI into the GSA's start URLs configuration. In version 6.10 of the GSA software, this is under "Crawl and Index - Crawl URLs - Start Crawling from the Following URLs".

Now tell the GSA that sitemap changes frequently. Enter the same sitemap URI in "Crawl and Index - Freshness Tuning - Crawl Frequently".

In this way, any page you activate from the CQ5 author will go to the publisher, show up in the sitemap, and be automatically crawled from the GSA. It will take the GSA up to an hour to crawl the newly activated content, assuming a page population of less than 15,000.